# JQuery - Html ID names that have windows file names is silently removing slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a terrible html id, something like `<a id="c:\foo.filename" ... />`

My JQuery plugin is getting this fired as C:foo.filename -- it seems jQuery is removing the slash.

Is this some known behavior that is trying to behave according to a spec? Can we not have \ in html identifiers?

Code:

```
     table.treetable("expandNode", "can&#39;t find file c:\foo.filename");
```

Jquery TreeTable code:

```
$.fn.treetable = function (method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        return $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.treetable");
    }
};
```

The arguments array's 2nd parameter is my filename based id, and this one has \ removed when it enters the function!

Comment: *"My JQuery plugin is getting this fired as C:foo.filename"* What does that mean exactly? How are you getting the ID? What are you doing with it? If I use as much jQuery as possible, I still get the ID correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/7eut3ujp/. Without more info (and code), we can't really help you. I can only tell you that jQuery is not manipulating IDs.

Comment: Why would you even do something like this?

Comment: Its a  bad idea to give a file path as an idea. May be you mean `href`, but relative path is a better idea.

Comment: Backslashes aren't valid ID characters. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: your example is working fine in this fiddle tho: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/w61xea0c/)

Comment: I'm using Jquery TreeTable and doing the following : table.treetable("expandNode", "My ID which is a filename: C:\foo.filename");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use "\" inside a Javascript String, it's an "escape" character, in your case you probably need to escape your escape character: "C:\\foo.filename"

If it's still not working, try to replace your backslash by "%2F"